# Configure Shiny app to display mathjax text out as HTML Preview by default

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, mathjax

I'm Building a dashboard using the packages shiny and shinydashboard, The issue I am having is when I try to include a math symbol inline with text when the app is launched it always smaller than its surrounding text. When the app is launched and right click on a math symbol and navigate to

> Math Setting>Math Render> the switch from HTML-CSS to HTML Preview it becomes the correct size. Wondering why this is the case and how I can make appear as the correct size by default so I don't have users switch HTML preview when they launch the app.

I tried adding the follow to change my Mathjax configuration upon the apps launch but it didn't seem to have any effect:

```r
tags$div(HTML("<script type='text/x-mathjax-config' >
                MathJax.Hub.Config({
                showProcessingMessages: true,
                jax: ['input/TeX', 'output/PreviewHTML'],
                });
                </script >
                "))
```

Here is a basic version of what I'm dealing with when ran the Mu symbol is much smaller than the other text.

```r
header <- dashboardHeader(
  #Set the title and title size of the dashboard. This will be located in top left coner of app.
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 400
)


# Sidebar Layout
# Contains the design for collapsable sidebar of the dashboard which allows users to navigate to its differnt pages.
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    # Each item navigates the dashboard to its corresponding page
    menuItem("Inputs", tabName = "inputs",icon = icon("angle-right"))
  )
)

#Boday Layout
# Contains the design for each indivual page listed within the side bar
body <- dashboardBody(
  withMathJax(),
  tags$div(HTML("<script type='text/x-mathjax-config' >
                MathJax.Hub.Config({
                showProcessingMessages: true,
                jax: ['input/TeX', 'output/PreviewHTML'],
                });
                </script >
                ")),
  dashboardBody(
    # TabItemS refrences theset of dashboard pages as whole
    tabItems(

      # First Pages contents
      tabItem(


        tabName = "inputs",
        h1("Here is the Problem"),
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 4,
              h3("This symobl \\(\\mu\\) is much smaller")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

  ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)

  server <- function(input, output) {



  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get µ with the correct size when I try your code. Maybe the browser ? What is the browser you use ? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I'm actually using R studio to launch it, when I run the app externally through a browser the size is fine, I'm just confused as to why when its run through Rstudio the size would be off?

Comment: There are many rendering issues with the RStudio browser.